# preserving colors in write command

Tags: python, linux

I'm using the write command to send messages to friends , I made a simple script that turns the text we give into ASCII art as follows:

**ascii.py**

```
import pyfiglet
from termcolor import cprint
import sys,random
f,t = '',''
fonts = list(pyfiglet.FigletFont.getFonts())
if sys.argv[-1] in fonts:
    f = sys.argv[-1]
    t = sys.argv[1:-1]
else:
    f = random.choice(fonts)
    t = sys.argv[1:]
cprint(pyfiglet.figlet_format(' '.join(t),str(f)),'red','on_blue',['bold'])
print(t)
```

Then I use the following command to send message:

```
python ascii.py hi graffiti | write neo
```

when I run the run the command without pipe i.e., `python ascii.py hi graffiti`, I get the following output:

[image]

But when I run `python ascii.py hi graffiti | write neo` , the colors are not being displayed instead some extra characters are being displayed as show below:

[image]

so how do I preserve colors so that they reach to the person at other end??

Comment: The strange characters are the escape-codes the terminal needs to perform the actual coloring. (edit) ok, I looked up write. There needs to be more investigation on why the escape-codes aren't intepreted.

Comment: @deets , the `write` is a buil-in linux command to send message to other people connected to the server, the `neo` is my username and i am sending the message to myself in this example

Comment: I just found that, too. I'll look into why escape-codes are mangled.

Comment: don't use  `output  >> input  >> output` all together :))

Comment: This is a security feature, not a bug. You don't want to write code that writes commands to someone's terminal, followed by triggering a copy-pand-paste to execute those commands. (Yes, that exploit used to be possible; I've been in the room -- about 15 years ago -- when someone implemented and tested it).

Comment: Hmm. Actually, that may have relied on sloppy permissions for gpm, now that I think about it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so that exploit won't work anymore?, what am I trying is not possible?

Comment: @PruthviRaj, correct, what you're trying is not possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Python isn't removing the colours; they're there:
These start some formatting

```
^[[1m^[[44m^[[31m
```

And this ends formatting

```
^[[0m
```

for instance, try this on your command line

```
$ printf '\e[1;31mHello, World!\e[0m\n'
```

you'll get the text in red, but not the formatting characters. This is because your *terminal* has interpreted the characters.

If you then do this, you'll see the formatting characters are still there. This is because when the terminal gets the data from write, it doesn't interpret the escape sequences.

```
$ printf '\e[1;31mHello, World!\e[0m\n' | write neo
```

What's happening is that the escape sequences '\e[1;31m' and '\e[0m' are being converted to their related byte values. You can see this by doing a hexdump of the data

```
$ printf '\e[1;31mHello, World!\e[0m\n' | hexdump
0000000 5b1b 3b31 3133 486d 6c65 6f6c 202c 6f57
0000010 6c72 2164 5b1b 6d30 000a               
0000019
$ printf '\\e[1;31mHello, World!\\e[0m\n' | hexdump
0000000 655c 315b 333b 6d31 6548 6c6c 2c6f 5720
0000010 726f 646c 5c21 5b65 6d30 000a          
000001b
```

See the start and end bytes are different? Write is receiving the formatting bytes, but printing out their related escape sequences.

I don't know exactly why write doesn't interpret the escape characters on the client side, but it's likely due to security (these escape sequences can do more than just change the font).

If you want pretty colours, you won't be able to use *write*.

Comment: *harumph* re: `echo -e` -- the POSIX specification for echo literally *doesn't allow* a compliant implementation to do anything but print `-e` on its output in response to that command. Consider using `printf` instead -- and see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections. (F'rinstance, the very first line of APPLICATION USAGE: "It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.")

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Tangential, but a good point. I've updated my examples.

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%b' 'sequence'` (for the unescaped form) and `printf '%s' 'sequence'` (for the literal form) rather than needing two differently-escaped versions of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I ran a small test, and it seems the problem is the `write`-command must do some shenannigans that don't seem to be parametrizable.

I wrote this small python-script which on my mac will write to another terminal (the same one picked by `write`), and it will color the output:

```
with open('/dev/ttys009', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write('\x1b[35mfoobar\x1b[30m\n')
```

So I guess you'll have to re-create `write` yourself, by looking at `/dev/tty*` for the given user, and then just open that file and write.

Comment: but I don't have permission to access the `tty*`

Comment: at our college I am not even admin, I'm just an user

Comment: Ah. It might have worked for me only because I send a message to myself. I did try & google the source for `write` etc, but didn't find it. It's a too generic name... It might be doing something special, and in the end the whole thing is impossible because it uses some kernel-function that will always prevent escapes code from being rendered :( But I don't know.

Comment: yeah thanks for the help, I was just doing this for fun, was wondering if there was a way to do it :) +1